# Web Disk Cpanel Windows 7

Tags: ssl, cpanel, webdav

I created a Web Disk at my remote server using and now I am trying to access it at Windows 7 and 8. I downloaded VBS script and also tried connecting using manual instructions provided in cpanel.

**Problems**

1. For some reasons it only connects at port 2077 and not 2078 even when I select digest authentication. My sever is secured by SSL certificate.
2. It disconnects the drive after few seconds and will not connect again. It triggers 'network path not found' error. I have tried enabling NETBIOS over TCP/IP but still no luck. It partially works if I logout and log back in but again disconnects after few seconds.

**Desired Output**

1. It should connect using port 2078
2. The connection should be persistent and I do not have to log out and log back in if I want to reconnect.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old post but maybe this will help you.

In Windows 7 Basic authentication cannot be persisted by the Credential Manager in Windows 7, this is new to the OS.
The only way with Basic authentication mode to reconnect is to disconnect the drive and reconnect again, because WinHttp is not able to retrieve saved Basic and Digest credentials.
For persistent connections ensure that an authentication scheme is selected that allows to have persistent credentials through a reboot.
For example Kerberos for authentication or certificate based authentication will work.

## WORKAROUND

Check source for the workaround.

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2673544